# How do I tell what components are in an item?

Tags: fallout-4

I enjoy crafting, this requires a lot of components. I've got loads of wood and steel but I need rarer items like screws, gears and circuitry. Is there a way to tell what components an item contains?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you go into your inventory, select the item and its components will be displayed above its weight/value:

[image]

Alternatively if you hit the Inspect button (PC: X) this will bring up the item by itself, its components will be displayed on the bottom left:

[image]

Comment: So there's no way to tell before you pick it up?

Comment: @Coomie no, but after a while you'll know what typically gives what.  Things that look complicated/mechanical will typically have circuits.  Advanced guns and stuff will give screws (assuming you got the perk to scavenge them).  Duct tape and wonder glue gives adhesive, etc.

Comment: @z Yeah, I've gotten used to some things, but then I found an antique globe and it had cork in it. How do I tell what else has cork in it? I guess I just have to collect everything...

Comment: @Coomie If you go to the junk tab in your inventory, you can switch to the "Component View". If you scroll down to the component you are looking for, like cork, it will show a list of items that have cork in them. I imagine these are just the ones you are carrying, but I'm not sure. Might be useful to take all from your main workshop and see what has what in it, then put all the junk back. Also, you can mark a component as important from this view, and any item that can break into that component will have a magnifying glass next to its name before you pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

This may already be a bit obvious but if you are near your workshop, use it (press <kbd>E</kbd>) to enter the item inspector, or hold <kbd>V</kbd> anywhere inside of a settlement, and then look around at the various items you find lying around the settlement. From this view, you get the option to scrap an item. Press the <kbd>R</kbd> button to scrap the item(X on XBox, Square on PS), and it will also list the component parts.

[image]

Of course, this is really only useful while you are near your settlements, but it may help to give a quick impression of what various kinds of items contain without needing to pick them up first...